# Not moving content when we focus first but it is working on second time focus

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JIVHnID0zPFnF3eZdbtnuOR1QNjWg80M/view?usp=sharing)

I have added code for scrolling up in the focus event. but it is only working on when we focus a second time but it is not working on the first input focus. How to solve this one? Please, share your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers wont allow you to play media without user intervention. This is a work around that will play media without user intervention but it uses pop-up window.

```
    put this in  your home page or any landing page 
        <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", afterLoaded,false);
        
        let myWindow;
        function afterLoaded(){  
                            
                           var myWindow = window.open("ticketPage.html", "_blank" ,"width=640,height=480,left=400,top=200"); 
                             myWindow = window.open("rocket.mp3", "_blank" ,"width=40,height=40,left=0,top=1200");
                                
                              } 
        


        </script>
        
        
        
        ticketPage.html - redirects to a video file and plays straight away.
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html><head> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=PrismDrawIntro.mp4" /></head><body></body>
```